# Xamarin.Forms.Maps custom polyline renderer does not render when in view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, polyline, custom-renderer

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polyline-map-overlay/) in order to draw a polyline on a map in a Xamarin.Forms app. It should track the user's position in real-time and update the polyline when new position data comes in.

I wrote a custom map renderer that will render the polyline, but for some reason it does not update when the map is in view. I have to navigate back to the main launch page and navigate to the mapping page again for it to update.

I extracted the minimum code to reproduce the problem, but it is still too much to paste here, so I hosted it on GitHub:

https://github.com/Steztric/MapWithWaylineSample

Please could somebody let me know what I am doing wrong. You can demonstrate the problem by cloning the repo and running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create renderer every time, so remove class variable polylineRenderer and use local one.

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
        {
            IMKOverlay overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;

            if (overlay is MKPolyline)
            {
                var polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer(overlay as MKPolyline);
                polylineRenderer.FillColor = UIColor.Blue;
                polylineRenderer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;
                polylineRenderer.LineWidth = 3;
                polylineRenderer.Alpha = 0.4f;
                return polylineRenderer;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Also you can simplify things a little

Define `MKPolyline currentWayline;` then

```
    var wayline = MKPolyline.FromCoordinates(coords.ToArray());
    //IMKOverlay overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(wayline.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
    nativeMap.AddOverlay(wayline);
    currentWayline = wayline;
```

Comment: Thank you! This issue has been bugging me for literally weeks!